# Unable to display binary to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding, base64

I am trying to get an image from a URL by using Ajax and want to convert this into data URL.

so far I have done following things("ALL DOES NOT WORK :(")

```
            sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
                        url : newURL,
                        mimeType: 'text/plain',
                        requestHeaders: {"responseType": "arraybuffer"},
                        onSuccess:function(response){
                        console.log(newURL);
                               var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = function(){
                                  var dataURL = reader.result;
                                  var output = document.getElementById(imageID);
                                  output.src = dataURL;

                                 };
                                 var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "image/png"});
                                 console.log(blob);
                                 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
                              }
```

This above code return data url but that does not display any image(corrupted).

I have done below thing also :

- First converted response binary string into array like below

```js
var bytes = new Uint8Array(response.length);
for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++)
    bytes[i] = response.charCodeAt(i);
```

- Now I converted above array into base64 like below

```js
function Uint8ToString(u8a){
  var CHUNK_SZ = 0x8000;
  var c = [];
  for (var i=0; i < u8a.length; i+=CHUNK_SZ) {
    c.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8a.subarray(i, i+CHUNK_SZ)));
  }
  return c.join("");
}
// Usage
var u8 = bytes;
var b64encoded = btoa(Uint8ToString(u8));
```

- make data URI with above base64 like below

```js
var dataurl = 'data:image/png;base64,'+b64encoded;
```

But nothing is working.

Below is the end point url to get image from

```html
http://featherfiles.aviary.com/2014-10-24/f93707f9c1472f8a/7892b73db1d947adb7bc536d5d03e5c0.png
```

Please help me as I am not able to understand how to solve this :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the blob of image correctly? i.e. it's size is that of the image right? 
If yes , then you might be just missing this line (the creation of blobUrl from blob)

```
var blob = new Blob([response], {type: "image/png"});
var blobUrl= URL.createObjectURL(blob);       //create blobUrl from blob
console.log(blob);
console.log(blobUrl)
reader.readAsDataURL(blobUrl);
```

Comment: have you implemented my answer and checked if it worked?

Comment: It gives following error :Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

Comment: This request have cross domain issue and I am doing this on salesforce proxy server so unable to replicate this on plnkr. I can share my screen with you if you are available